# c# MongoAuthenticationException when connecting to remote mongodb (3.2)

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm trying to connect to remote mongodb (3.2 version) server using following C# code:

```
  _client = new MongoClient(
                      new MongoClientSettings
                      {
                          Credentials = new[]
        {
                MongoCredential.CreateMongoCRCredential("test", "usernamex", "password")
        },
                          Server = new MongoServerAddress("xx.xx.xx.xxx", 27017)
                      });

        var databases = _client.ListDatabasesAsync().Result;
```

It raises a following exception: 
MongoAuthenticationException - Unable to authenticate username "usernamex" on database "test". 
On remote server user "usernamex" exists.
On remote server netstat -a -n gives xx.xx.xx.xxx:27017 connection established.
 Any idea?

Comment: Where did you create the user? in the database itself or in the admin db?

Comment: I tried with both options, database itself and admin db

Comment: Did you try to connect with the shell or some tool like robomongo or Mongo chef? (mongo xx.xx.xx.xx:27017/test -u usernamex -p password --authenticationDatabase admin --verbose)

Comment: As i'm new to mongodb you gave me a valuable info about robomongo tool. It's very intuitive and provided a solution to my problem immediately. In my code I used MongoCRCredential instead of CreateCredential.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all those facing such a problem in the future here is the solution:

1. ensure that user in connection string has indeed sufficient rights.
   Using mongo shell it would be:   > use test  > db.getUser("usernamex")
2. replace following line of code:

   MongoCredential.CreateMongoCRCredential("test", "usernamex", "password")

with this one:

```
MongoCredential.CreateCredential("test", "usernamex", "password")
```